# How does performance measurement tool 'perf' actually work?

Tags: performance, perf-event

**perf** is a tool which accesses the performance counter registers of an machine  and gives out metrics to user to analyze the system performance.

What I am curious about is, when I read the parts of code. I see perf reading something from a memory mapped area (I feel it reads an area which is been written by the kernel), it is also reading /proc/modules, but I could not find any code related to actual read of hardware registers of machine.

- How does perf actually record its samples?
- How does it identify what function is an executable is executing?
- How does it know the symbols?

Does the kernel also have a module of perf inside (apart from /tools to convey the application 'perf' running in user space)?

Can anyone brief me about the internal working in detail?

Comment: Have you look at the perf documentation and source code yet ?  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/perf

Comment: yeah i am currently going through it, but quite confused with its modularity, i see some new things like kernel maps, module creations etc, any way thanks for suggestion, its documentation stresses more on usage of tool rather than its actual working